# Running tensorflow from another code base

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, tensorflow

I'm hoping someone can help me out here as I feel like I've literally tried everything.

I've followed the tensorflow for poets tutorial for image classification and it works great. I've now built a node application and I'm using a package called python-shell which lets you run python scripts, which also works (I am aware of tensorflow js but I need the performance of py). I've plugged it up so that it can run my tensorflow image classifier and it seems to work...ish. The scripts are definitely executing but when it comes to reading retrained_labels.txt this is where it fails.

The error I get back is:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: tf_files/retrained_labels.txt : The system cannot find the path specified.`

From what I've read this is a paths issue and I've already tried to specify absolute paths in my retrain script, but it doesn't solve the issue. However the issue isn't really with tensorflow as that works perfectly as a stand alone script.

I'm at a complete loss so any suggestion is much appreciated.

For some more context the code I need to run is:

`py -m scripts.label_image --graph="tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --image=tf_files/dogs/test.jpg`

In my node app I'm running this (and I've also played with different script paths, absolute paths, relative paths and every combination I can think of for the last 6 hours)

```
let options = {
    scriptPath: './playground/',
    args: ['--graph', './playground/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb', '--image', './playground/tf_files/dogs/test.jpg']
};

PythonShell.run('scripts/label_image.py', options, function (err, pyRes) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send({ result: pyRes });
});
```

Is there a way I can maybe run a python script which then goes and runs this?

`py -m scripts.label_image --graph="tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --image=tf_files/dogs/test.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed by hard coding absolute path in image_label.py